# Указать контейнер для Pjax Yii2

Tags: yii2, pjax

Возможно ли указать для Pjax контейнер, в котором ему надо обновлять контент?

Comment: `<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>`
тут обновляется содержимое
`<?php Pjax::end(); ?>` Или что вы хотите?

Comment: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#pjax-options

Comment: нет, мне не совсем это надо. это я знаю. и имею ввиду, что если есть div с id=tabs, могу ли я указать для Pjax, что надо контент обновлять в нем?

Comment: Оборачиваете этот див в пджакс, вставляете туда невидимую ссылку, и когда нужно обновить его то яваскриптом делаете клик по этой невидимой ссылке. Таким костылём можно в принципе, или почище методом вроде таким - https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#pjaxclick